# Passing a variable from a private method

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a private method "questionSubmitActionPerformed", that creates a variable "input". I would like to use this variable in another method, called "compareAnswers". Since my IDE of choice (Netbeans) won't let me change the private into public, is there any way to pass the variable down to the method? Here's a excerpt of my code:

```
 private void questionSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    //gets input and clears answer area
    input = questionAnswer.getText();
    //calls the comparison, returns Yes or No 
    compareAnswers();
 }

 private void compareAnswers() {
    //compare input to the ArrayList
}
```

Note that just changing the "private" to "public" in the first method is not an option for me

Comment: yeah do... `private void compareAnswers(String input)` and change `compareAnswers();` to `compareAnswers(input);`

Comment: "Since my IDE of choice (Netbeans) won't let me change the private into public"
?????

Comment: The first comment is the right option. And, you are not creating the input variable in your method, you are not declaring it there, so your description is incorrect, it is defined outside the method. Changing variables to public and changing methods to public just to solve access issues should not be your first choice.

Comment: Where and how have you declared the variable `input`?

Comment: From the looks of it you wouldn't even need to change the second method to include the input; aren't they in the same class? Although, based on the code comments; it *would* need to be changed to return the results of the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are very confused with `modifiers and methods` . it seems that both of your methods are `in the same class`.and what you want to do is pass a value to another `method`
and it has nothing to do with `public or private`(modifiers) what you should do is 
make a `parameter` inside your method, in your case

```
private void compareAnswers(String input) {
    //compare input to the ArrayList
}
```

you can execute the method by : `compareAnswers("abc");`

and `modifiers` change the `visibility of the properties`, if its `private` then you wont be able to `access` those properties from `another class`. read more about `modifiers` http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_modifier_types.htm

Comment: Thank you, and 3kings from above, I am confusing methods with modifiers.......so the private and all that only refers to the class, has nothing to do with accessing variables in other methods?

Comment: yes but if your properties are marked as private you wont be able to access them from another class

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have all this code in class `abc` So it should look something like this:

```
class abc{

    private String Input;
    //Some other variables declared.

    //some constructors

     private void questionSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        //gets input and clears answer area
        input = questionAnswer.getText();
        //calls the comparison, returns Yes or No 
        compareAnswers();
     }

     private void compareAnswers() {
        //compare input to the ArrayList
    }

    //Some other methods.

}
```

If this is the structure of the program, then I don't understand why do you require to pass the variable to another method? The variable `input` is already accessible in the method `compareAnswers()`.

Now, still if you insist that the variable be passed to the method `compareAnswers` then change the signature of the method to :

```
private void compareAnswers(String input)
```

and also call the method inside `questionSubmitActionPerformed` as :

```
compareAnswers(input);
```

**After the Comment**

From what your comment states, I understand the structure of you program would be something like this :

```
class abc{

    //Some other variables declared.

    //some constructors

    public void someMethod{
        //Some things done;
        String input;
        //Some other things done;
    }

     private void questionSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        //gets input and clears answer area
        input = questionAnswer.getText();
        //calls the comparison, returns Yes or No 
        compareAnswers();
     }

     private void compareAnswers() {
        //compare input to the ArrayList
    }

    //Some other methods.

}
```

If this is the condition, then how are you able to compile this class in the first case? Since here the variable `input` is a local variable for the method `someMethod` and it does not exist after the method `someMethod` has completed execution.

In order that you can access the variable `input` outside of the method `someMethod` is either by returning the `input` variable from the `someMethod` and storing it as an instance variable.

OR By declaring the variable `input` as an instance variable from the first as I had exemplified in my initial code before this edit.

OR By calling `questionSubmitActionPerformed` from inside the `someMethod` and passing the variable `input` as a parameter to this method.

Comment: The variable is created in a public method, but its declaration happens in a private method......will I be able to access what the variable actually contains from the compareAnswers method?

Comment: @3.14ed_Piper I have edited my answer to accommodate for your comment

Answer (score 0):

Based on 3kings's response as an answer:

I used

```
 compareAnswers(String input) {}
```

in conjunction with

```
 compareAnswers(input);
```

and it worked! 
Thank you!